# How to automatically focus the editor in the expansion panel content on open of expansion panel in angular?

Tags: angular, quill, autofocus, mat-expansion-panel

I have an expansion panel with "Write a response" header. On opening the expansion panel, I'm having a quill editor.

I need to focus the quill editor on expanding the panel.

```
<mat-expansion-panel #panel1>
<mat-expansion-header> <span>"Write a Response"</span> </mat-expansion-header>
<quill-editor [ngModel]="htmlText" (onContentChanged)="onContentChanged($event)" placeholder="placeholder"></quill-editor>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

I tried autofocus, cdkFocusInitial, (focus)="myMethod()", still not working. Can someone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you will have to use @ViewChild.

**First Add an id to the quil-editor - #editor**

```
<mat-expansion-panel #panel1>
<mat-expansion-header> <span>"Write a Response"</span> </mat-expansion-header>
<quill-editor #editor [ngModel]="htmlText" (onContentChanged)="onContentChanged($event)" placeholder="placeholder"></quill-editor>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Then go over to the ts file and import ViewChild and AfterViewInit from angular/core.
Then

```
export class ComponentName implement AfterViewInit{
@ViewChild('editor') editorElementRef : ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.editorElementRef.nativeElement.focus();
  }
}
```

So the above code, moves the focus to the editor once the view is initialized.

Comment: Tried this, its working, but not as expected. It focuses the quill editor once and the focus goes back to the expansion panel. So I am not able to directly start typing in the editor.